# To big endian or to little endian?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, hardware, endianness

let's say that we ignore the target and source hardware for a moment.  So, what's the better endian style to go with -- big or small?

I'm just trying to go with consensus / convention on this one.  The best guidance I've received so far is "it depends" so always specify.  That's fine.  I'll do that.

*However*, in this situation there is no need to be one way or the other.  There's no legacy, so I thought, "what would be the cleanest choice for current & emerging hardware."

Comment: Gulliver's Travels is required reading material.

Comment: Big-end / little-end as terms come from Swift, who was giving an example of pointless argument in discussing which end of an egg to open.

Comment: Are you actually coding so close to the CPU that this matters?

Comment: it's more the asthetic of "by convention" I'm after.  On the CPU question -- me no.  Others nearby -- yes.

Comment: The answer is of course "Yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer is it depends

If you just want a choice then Since in Big Endian high order byte comes first ,you can always check positive or negative from the first byte.

Comment: You check for positive or negative like this `x < 0`, *regardless* of endianness. Endianness has nothing to do with positive or negative. It's about representation, not values. Please don't obfuscate your code because of this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't choose. Just use whatever your compiler/platform uses. That gives no hassle and just works.

If you are doing raw network stuff, you may want to convert things to/from network endianness though, which is big endian. But don't mess up your whole code because of that. Just do the conversion when you get to the network writing part.

Comment: it's an n-language situation.  I'd like all languages to play together nicely.  So I need to choose unfortunately.

Comment: @sgtz: Is it the same platform? Do the languages use different endianness?

Comment: Language isn't really the problem, is the system - if it's homogeneous, no worries, if heterogeneous, then you need a common format for communication - and typically this is big-endian. But habit is always convert to local format before handling the data (and vice versa)

Comment: not necessarily the same platform or machine.

Comment: @sgtz choose any one(e.g. big-endian) and do the conversions for those using little-endian

Comment: @sgtz: Use the default on each machine. Convert to one of them when writing/reading data to the network or to a persistence store. Any one is fine.

Comment: @Nim by habit is a given (for safety)... but underneath I'd like to resemble convention (or forward convention).  Sounds like that's big endian.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever is predominant in your hardware. Or use "network byte order" (big endian) because the internet does. Or pick one at random. It's unimportant.

Comment: +1 I wondered what "network byte order" was.  ty.  Another vote for big endian for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Just pick one.

This is a topic of endless debate. One does not hold a particular advantage over the other.